# updating a JSON object in a list of JSON objects

Tags: json, reactjs

So I'm watching a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hCPQ6rXFvcE&list=WL&index=28&t=0s) on updating a list of JSON objects. At 1:23, in the `updateTodo()` method, I notice the way he updates the JSON object(the `todo` item) from the JSON list using `.find()`. Directly, edits it using, `todo.name=data.name` then `setState({todos:todos})`.

Can someone explain that? Don't you need to loop through the list of JSON object than replace the specific JSON object when some condition is met? I'm confused why he didn't loop through the todos list to replace the value. Can someone explain to me why?

The code snippet:

```
updateTodo(data) {
        axios.put('/api/todo/update/' + data.id, data)
            .then(response => {
                    let todos = [...this.state.todos];
                    let todo = todos.find(todo => {
                        return todo.id === data.id;
                    });

                    todo.name = data.name;
                    
                    this.setState({
                        todos: todos,
                    });
                
            }).catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
    }
```

Any insight is appreciated. Thank you for reading.

Comment: [`Array.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) loops through the array until it finds the appropriate element or exits with `undefined` if it can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In React you can't update state directly. so by doing

```
let todos = [...this.state.todos];
```

It create a copy of the `todos` property which is in the state and It doesn't reference to the value which is in the state.

```js
let todoId = 2;
let todos = [
    {id: 1, name: "todo 1", done: false},
    {id: 2, name: "todo 1", done: false},
    {id: 3, name: "todo 1", done: false}
]

let todo = todos.find((todo) => todo.id == todoId);


// if I update any attribute of the previous toto variable it will also update it value in the `todos`

todo.name = "updated todo name";

console.log(todos);
```

As you can see in the example above the when I perform the update of the name in the `todo` variable It also update It reference in the `todos`;

Even if I don't update directly the todo in the `todos` like `todos[2].name = "updated toto name"`, this code update the `todo` by reference. `todo` point to the values which is in the `todos` array.

That is the reason why He create a new Array of `this.state.todos` by doing `[...this.state.todos]` and this doesn't have any references to the `this.state.todos` to avoid Array References.

You can learn more about [JavaScript Arrays: Value vs Reference](https://www.dyn-web.com/javascript/arrays/value-vs-reference.php) here

**And the call to `find` have the effect of return the first element when the callback return true**

Which that no need to loop through the `todos` list

Read more at [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) Documentation